# How to track code commits of particular users in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I lead a quite a few teams and would like to get notified of the code commits of select set of users in Azure DevOps. How do I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops) in the category `Code (TFVC) -> Code is checked in` for each developer you would like to track. In the filter criteria you specify `Committer = john@example.com` where the `john@example.com` is the email address of the developer you would like to track

[image: Edit notification form Azure DevOps]

You can find all your personal notification by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/navigating-the-ui?view=azure-devops#open-your-personal-notifications) in the Azure DevOps documentation.